Major IMAP services aren’t connecting to imap_open() in PHP
When connecting to a major IMAP service in PHP, I get a "Connection refused" error. I don't understand why this is happening.
I have tried iCloud (imap.mail.me.com), Yahoo! (imap.mail.yahoo.com), Gmail, (imap.gmail.com), Outlook (outlook.office365.com) and even Yandex to connect to my PHP script.
$email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'my app pass word';

$imap_host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'; //Gmail
$connection = imap_open($imap_host, $email, $password);

if ($connection === false) {
    die('Failed to connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
}

However, using my domain's IMAP works fine. What am I doing wrong? Do they block IMAP connections?
The IMAP extension is installed. I am using shared web hosting with cPanel.

"Do they block IMAP connections?" Probably.

I am not surprised that Gmail blocks authorization from (PHP) webhosts. It is for security reasons to block spammers, scammers etc.

For clarification, I know that Gmail blocks IMAP connections. It was probably a bad example.
